# Using SMO from PowerShell, is there a way to state that a jobstep output file should be appended and not overwritten?

Tags: sql-server-2012, powershell, smo

I deploy multiple SQL Server jobs to a fleet of servers using a PowerShell script. I can create the job steps, success fail action, and even the output file. This all works on multiple servers. What I cannot determine is how to specify that the **output file is to be appended** to instead of overwritten.

The following is the section from my main script. `$Job` is populated in a previous step.

```
$JobStep = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Agent.JobStep') ($Job, 'MyJobStepName')
$JobStep.ID = 1
$JobStep.SubSystem = 'PowerShell'
$Command = 'dir d:\'
$JobStep.Command   = $Command
$JobStep.OnSuccessAction = 'GotoNextStep'
$JobStep.OnFailAction    = 'GotoNextStep'
$JobStep.OutputFileName  = 'D:\MyJobFile.txt'
$JobStep.Create()
```

I have been using [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.jobstep.outputfilename.aspx) page as a reference.

I modified one of the steps using SQL Server Management Studio and traced the result. This looks promising. I can issue a SQL command after I create the jobsteps.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_jobstep @job_id=N'12156dcb-c8cd-4267-901a-55175dd44960', @step_id=1 ,
        @flags=2
```

Comment: Not as per [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.aspx) page.

Comment: I see you already solved your problem. As you already know, SMO calls existing procedures so the documentation for those should be usefull with SMO, in this case it's using [sp_add_job_step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-add-jobstep-transact-sql)

Comment: @SqlWorldWide the page that you referenced has it `The JobStepFlags enumeration is a list of constant values that specify the file to which to append job history information.`

Comment: @Kin thank you so much, do not know why I missed it.

Comment: What is SMO? Do you have a reference?

Comment: @Petermortensen see [this](http://m.sqlmag.com/powershell/using-sql-server-management-objects-powershell) article.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is more along below lines

```
$jobStep.JobStepFlags = "AppendToLogFile"
  #call the alter to modify
$jobStep.Alter()
  #display it
$jobStep.JobStepFlags
```

Comment: This would be correct. You can find the values associated to this property [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.jobstepflags.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
$jobStep.JobStepFlags = "AppendToLogFile"
```

or

```
$jobStep.JobStepFlags = 2
```